# Find the partial derivatives of the function $f(x)=\|x\|^{\alpha}$ outside of $(0,0)$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

We had the following solved problem in our lecture which I didn't quite fully understand.

Find the partial derivatives of the function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$
$$f(x)=||x||^{\alpha}$$
outside of $(0,0)$ when $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.
With what constant values $\alpha$  do the partial derivatives also exist at $(0,0)$?

With Chain Rule the partial derivatives of  $f$ are
$$\partial _if(x)=\alpha||x||^{\alpha-1}\times D||x||.$$

Since $$D||x||=D\left(\sqrt{x^2_1+...+x^2_n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\times 2x_i(x^2_1+...+x^2_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=x_i(x^2_1+...+x^2_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=||x||^{-1}$$
we can write
$$\partial _if(x)=\alpha||x||^{\alpha-1}\times D||x||=\alpha||x||^{\alpha-1}\times ||x||^{-1}=\alpha||x||^{\alpha-2}$$
when $x\neq 0$ and $i\le n$.

When $\alpha -2\ge0 \Rightarrow \alpha \ge 2$ and we set $0^0=1$ and $\alpha\gt 2$ if $0^0\neq 1$, the partial derivative exists at $(0,0)$.

My questions:

1. How did we get $$x_i(x^2_1+...+x^2_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=||x||^{-1}$$ since isn't $$x_i(x^2_1+...+x^2_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=x_i\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2_1+...+x^2_n}}=x_i \times ||x||^{-1}?$$
2. When we wrote out $$\partial _if(x)=\alpha||x||^{\alpha-2},$$ why did we have to define the part "when $i\le n$"? Isn't $i\le n$ anyways?
3. As for the last part of the solution "When $\alpha -2\ge0 \Rightarrow \alpha \ge 2$ and we set $0^0=1$ and $\alpha\gt 2$ if $0^0\neq 1$, the partial derivative exists at $(0,0)$", how did we figure out that the partial derivative doesn't exist when $a\lt 2$? Doesn't $f$ approach $0$ when $a\lt 2$? And how come it suddenly exists when we set out certain rules?

Comment: $D||x|| = x^T/||x||$. First you wrote only $x_i$ instead of $x$, then you also deleted the $x_i$. So 1) would be correct if you hadn't replaced $x^T$ by $x_i$ earlier on already.

Comment: Oh, I see. you first replaced $\partial_i$ with $D$ and then back. You should try to use a consistent notation.